# Cant Locate Image/Info.pm Module Error

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to get the resolution,width,height of the images in the specific file.

I have the following code.

```
#use strict;
use Image::Info qw(image_info dim);
use File::List;
#perl2exe_include Image::Info::JPEG;
#perl2exe_include PerlIO;       

my $file  = <ImageFilePath>;  
my $info = image_info($file);            
my $res = $info->{resolution};                
print "$$res[0]\n";
```

I have the Perl Version 5.16.3

I get the following error:

```
Can't locate Image/Info.pm in @INC (@INC contains: c:\program files\Perl\lib c:/program files/Perl/site/lib c:/program files/Perl/lib .) at Img_Res.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Img_Res.pl line 3.
```

Can anyone give me the solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

From the code part of question I am concluding that you are trying to create an executable using Perl2EXE, because you are using the line

```
#perl2exe_include Image::Info::JPEG;
```

and also assuming that you are running command

```
perl2exe c:\somepath\somescript.pl -o somescript.exe
```

The answer from @James Green is correct to an extent, however its incomplete (as in fails to explain his second bullet point).

You need to install "Image::Info" and any other modules that you are using (Use the answer from @James Green).

After installation, Open to windows explorer and locate the module that you just installed,
It will normally be in the following folders

```
"PERL_PATH\perl\lib"
"PERL_PATH\perl\site\lib"
"PERL_PATH\perl\vendor\lib"
```

Once you locate the module is installed in the one of the 3 locations above. Navigate to the location where Perl2EXE is installed.

```
PERL2EXE_PATH\perl2exe-XX.xx-Win\
```

Locate the folder with the current version of perl you are using. In your case the folder name should be

```
Win32-5.16.3 or Win64-5.16.3
```

Open the folder and locate the .conf file.
Edit the line with header libdir.

```
libdir=perl-Win32/site/lib;perl-Win32/lib;perl-Win32/vendor/lib;.
```

Ensure all the perl/lib directories are included in the search path.
Save it and rerun your command. This should work.

Sometimes even after all this the perl2exe command fails, this is due to the limitation of the program being able to decipher the qw command.
So to avoid this directly call the module (ex: use Module::Name;) in your code instead of using the qw.

Comment: I just saw this. Thanks for filling in the bits I skipped :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you've done two things:

- install the Image::Info module
- make sure @INC includes the path to wherever you installed the module

I see you're on Windows, which means you're likely using either Strawberry Perl, or ActiveState's Perl. If you're using Strawberry Perl you should have some success following the directions on http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html -- I believe ActiveState has its own built-in package manager, ppm, and to get started with that you'll want to look here: http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/ppm-perl-modules